# Ordered Logistic Regression With Data Collected in Multiple Time Periods

Tags: regression, time-series, logistic, ordered-logit

I have a dataset with cross-sectional data that was conducted in 8 separate time periods. In each period (roughly 1 year apart in time), roughly 3000 respondents (to be clear, in each time period different respondents are surveyed) were surveyed on basic demographic questions, as well as personality statements (1-5 scale) and movie genre viewing levels (1-3 scale - High, Medium, Low). The distribution of basic demo questions (age bracket, race, gender) is similar across the different time period samples.

I am trying to better understand how certain demographic information and personality qualities are associated with a respondent's affinity for a movie genre. Since the dependent variable has 3 ordered categories, my first thought was to attempt an ordered logistic regression. What I am a bit confused of is how to model the element of time for this.

My approach as of now is, keeping the data at a respondent level, assign each respondent the time period that he/she took the survey. And then trying an ordered logistic regression and including the set of time dummy variables, as well as interaction terms between the time dummy variables and the demo and personality questions, since these effects on movie genre viewing level may be different across time (or they may very well not be). So, simplifying the model (with only a few demo variables and a few personality variables) and using the Horror genre as an example:

Dependent variable = Horror Movie Viewing (High, Medium, Low)

Explanatory variables = Age, Gender, Race, Personality1, Personality2, Personality3, Time, interaction terms between all demo/personality and Time

(I'm sorry, I'm sure that can be structured better)

Could someone with more knowledge of time series speak to some of the issues that could arise by building a model like so? Or perhaps suggest another model that I should look more into? My approach was to keep at the respondent level, but should I pool each cross-section? Although I would only have 8 data points if so.

Thanks a lot for any help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: depending on how fancy you want to get, something like [MRT](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/MRT(1).pdf) might be relevant

Comment: also, how much do respondents change over time?  your first paragraph says they're different in each time period, while at the end you say you want to keep at respondent-level.  this indicates a non-trivial proportion were surveyed more than once